# How to find length of shortest unique substring and number of occurrences of all unique substrings of same length in a given string

Tags: string, algorithm

The problem is to find the length of the shortest unique substring and number of same length unique substring occurring in the string. For eg. "aatcc" will have "t" as the shortest length unique substring and length is 1 so the output will be 1,1. Another example is "aacc"  here the output will be 2,3 as strings are aa,ac,cc

I tried to solve it but could come up only with a brute Force solution which is to loop over all possible substrings. It exceeded the time limit.

I googled it and found some references to suffix array but not quite clear about it.
So what is the optimal solution for this problem?

**EDIT** : Forgot to mention the key requirement of the solution of that was required for this problem and that is to **NOT** use any library functions other than input and output functions to read and write from and to the standard input and the standard output respectively.

**EDIT**: I have found another solution using trie data structure.

```
Pseudocode:
for i from 1 to length(string) do
  for j from 0 to length(string)-1 do
     1. create a substring of length i from jth character
     2. if checkIfSeen(substring) then count-- else count++ 
  close inner for loop
  if count >= 1 then break
close outer for loop
print i(the length of the unique substring), count (no. of such substrings)

checkIfSeen(Substring) will use a trie data structure which 
will run O(log l) where l is the average length of the prefixes.
```

The time complexity of this algorithm would be O(n^2 log l) where if the average length of the prefixes is n/2 then the time complexity would be O(n^2 log n). Please point out the mistakes if there are and also ways to improve this running time if possible.

Comment: have you tried to start from the longest string s, truncate it from left and right to generate words of length l-1 (and so forth). Upon each word of same length, store them in a trie, and if found in the trie, do not truncate them for the next truncating step?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that my answer is based on program I wrote with Python, but can be applied to any programming language.

Now I believe brute force approach is indeed what you need to do in this problem. But what we can do to shorten the time is:

1. start the brute force from the smallest substring length, which is 1.
2. after looping through the string with substring length 1 (the data will look something like {"a":2, "t":1, "c":2} for "aatcc"), check if any substring appeared only once. If it did, count the occurrence by looping through the dictionary (in case of the example you gave, "t" only appeared once, so occurrence is 1).
3. After the occurrence is counted, break the loop so that it does not
   have to waste time on counting the rest of bigger substrings.
4. on 2:, if the unique substring was not found, reset the dictionary
   and try a bigger substring (the data can be something like {"aa": 1, "ac":1, "cc":1 for "aacc"}). Eventually the unique substring WILL be found no matter what (for example, in the string "aaaaa", the unique substring is "aaaaa" with the data {"aaaaa":1})

Here is the implementation in Python:

```
def countString(string):
    for i in range(1, len(string)+1): #start the brute force from string length 1
        
        dictionary = {}
        for j in range(len(string)-i+1):  #check every combination.
              
            #count the substring occurrences
            try:
                dictionary[string[j:j+i]] += 1
            except:
                dictionary[string[j:j+i]] = 1

        isUnique = False #loop stops if isUnique is True
        occurrence= 0
        for key in dictionary: #iterate through the dictionary
            if dictionary[key] == 1: #check if any substring is unique
                #if found, get ready to escape from the loop and increase the occurrence
                isUnique = True
                occurrence+=1

        if isUnique: 
            return (i, occurrence)

print(countString("aacc")) #prints (2,3)
print(countString("aatcc")) #prints (1,1)
```

I am pretty sure that this design is fairly fast, but there always should be a better way.

Comment: There is no way around generating all substring and that is for sure. But I think the trick lies in the part where we check if the substring is already found or not. This is the same solution that I had in my mind. This resulted in TLE.